# How to SUM a number field in Filemaker

Tags: sql, filemaker

I can COUNT text fields with the necessary changes to the below equation, but can neither COUNT nor SUM the number field.

size = number field

ExecuteSQL ( "
        SELECT
           SUM ( size )
        FROM
           Albums" ;
        "" ;
        ""
)

This calculation results in a ? in the data viewer.

Comment: If something doesn't work, it's very helpful to include error messages, etc.  And more helpful still to include example data, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I used SeedCode's SQLExplorer and came up with this.

ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT SUM (\"size\") FROM \"Albums\"" ; "" ; "" ; "")

Original calculation did not work **because SIZE is a reserved word.**

Oh, well. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

```
ExecuteSQL ( " SELECT SUM ( size ) || '' FROM Albums" ; "" ; "" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it and got the ?. I used SeedCode's SQL explorer and found the calculation above worked

Comment: What database system are you using ?